# How can I show all data model properties in TableView Cell at Swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I have data model :

```
struct SearchedModel {
    var yazar: [String]?
    var imageUrl: String?
    var kitapAdi: String?
    var basimTarihi: String?
    var sayfa: Int?
    var yayimci: String?
    var dil: String?
    var not: String?
    var durum: String?
    var aciklama: String?
    var satiscisi: String?
}
```

I need to show that model's all properties in `TableView Cell` because it is detail page. How can I show these datas in same table view's cells. I want to make table with each cell has model properties like first cell is `yazar`, second is `kitapAdi`, third is `basimTarihi` etc..

I take this data from another page and it is came with model like var `detailData = SearchedModel()`.

How can I make it? I don't want to make custom cell for every model properties.

Comment: I would create a table view with **static** cella and outlets.

Comment: I will search about static cell and outlet @vadian.